# Maintaining websocket connection in react router

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux, react-router

I have a React/Redux app using React Router for routing.

As part of this app I set up a websocket connection. An issue I'm facing is that when navigating directly to a url, the connection is dropped.

For example:

1. User lands on home page at `www.app.com/`
2. Websocket connection is established.
3. User naviagtes to `www.app.com/link` via React Router browserHistory (there is no code to establish any connection on this page).
4. Connection is maintained.

This works as expected. However:

1. User lands on home page at `www.app.com/`
2. Websocket connection is established.
3. User navigates directly to `/link` by entering it in the address bar (or refreshing the page after navigating to it via previous example.
4. Connection dropped.

Is this expected behaviour? If so are there any Redux/React Router patterns for avoiding it? Do I have to manually re-establish the connection every time?

Comment: Do you know about server-side vs client-side routing?

Comment: Up until now the plan had been for the app to be serverless. So everything is client side, and it will be hosted on S3 with Route53 to catch requests to anything other than `app.com/`

Comment: Not sure about the websocket part, but just with the React router part if you navigate manually to a link it will query the server for that file and if it only exists client side as a route then you'll get a 404 and it'll fail. To solve this you need a catch all path in the back end (like with express it'd be `app.get('*', (req, res) => {res.sendFile('index.html')});` that triggers if you manually type a URL in or refresh the page. In your case, for server-side only and websocket you'll need to set it so that a connection is established regardless of the specific React route (as Tiago said)

Comment: Yup I am aware of that issue, that's what I meant by 'catching' requests in my previous comment. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. When you refresh the page or navigate manually by typing the URL, the browser will go to the server again to load the files, including your javascript app (it may get it from the cache but the result is the same). Because of this your javascript code that is in memory, including the websocket connection, will be lost and all the scripts will be evaluated again.

There's no way around this. To always have a websocket connection open you can just open the connection in your app entry point script, regardless of what page the user is in.