# How to detect user leaves site?

Tags: redux, socket.io, react-router

I'm using `react-router`'s `BrowserRouter` and `Route` and `Redux`. I want to dispatch an action when a user leaves the site or logs out. I'm also using `socket.io`, but cannot rely on the `disconnect` because changes in pages within the site cause disconnects.

I looked at `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.onunload`, but they also don't work because they get called when I change pages in the site.

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Interesting problem - perhaps you could use `window.onunload` together with`window.location` to detect if someone has actually left your site when unload occurs (ie, by checking the location when unload occurs to see if the hostname has changed)?

Comment: (nice start up btw :-))

Comment: thanks for the compliment and the suggestion; I've been looking into it some more and I'm not sure if I can access the next location a user is going to because of privacy issues

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with React/Redux, but I suspect that its because your client's socket connection is being created within the views that are being created and destroyed. That would mean that you have a persistence problem.

Since Redux is meant for state management, you should store your socket instance there. If your user signs out then you can manually disconnect and discard the instance or if your user leaves your page then it will naturally just disconnect.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "client's socket connection is being created within the views that are being created and destroyed." I do have a persistent problem of the socket disconnecting and then having to reconnect on page changes. I tried storing socket into Redis and redux state, but the socket would disconnect. @Kris

Comment: After reading [Maintaining websocket connection in react router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42222616/6558244), I don't think there is a way to detect if a user leave the page. If they're authenticated though and their socket disconnects, you may be able to set that disconnect logic to run if that user doesn't connect after a certain amount of time

Comment: I thought about that; but the thing that pointed me away was the fact that I would have to account for the slowest internet connection. :(

Comment: @Hunter690 you might want to look into web workers. [Heres](https://crossbario.com/blog/Websocket-Persistent-Connections/) an article from 2014 talking about web workers and web sockets from 2014. Fortunately web workers are now supported in the majority of web browsers.